# Batch File to move mods

Tags: windows, batch-file, installation

I was originally going to very vague with this to not give it away but it seems easier to just tell.

I am writing a batch file named "XJSS Installer" to automatically check to see if java is installed (if not then install it), Install Forge, and move a folder named "mods" with (you guessed it, mods in it) to ".minecraft" in "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft" but I am having trouble with making a "universal mover"? Basically all I need is to be able to move "mods" to C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft but have it work on computers setup with different users (I mean like my friends PCs).

Comment: You do know that ```"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft"``` can be referenced more succinctly don't you? Try ```"%AppData%\.minecraft"``` instead.

Comment: You should not aks multiple questions at once.

Comment: You should not type half asleep. Pay the respect to those you ask for help that you write the request while you are able to do it the honor.